# Batching Tasks and Running them in Parallel

Tags: c#, .net

I have a List of items, and I would like to go through each item, create a task and launch the task. But, I want it to do batches of 10 tasks at once.

For example, if I have 100 URL's in a list, I want it to group them into batches of 10, and loop through batches getting the web response from 10 URL's per batch iteration.

Is this possible?

I am using C# 5 and .NET 4.5.

Comment: Why the batches?  Parallel.For will already do that, do you need any control over the batches?

Comment: BlockingCollection has a size.  Not exactly blocks but can have 10 in process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Parallel.For()` or `Parallel.ForEach()`, they will execute the work on a number of Tasks.

When you need precise control over the batches you could use a custom Partitioner but given that the problem is about URLs it will probably make more sense to use the more common `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` option.

Answer (score 0):

The Partitioner has a good algorithm for creating the batches depending also on the number of cores.

```
Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(from, to), range =>
{
    for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
    {
        // ... process i
    }
});
```